# How to extract content inside a label using beautiful soup in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I extracted the div class using beautiful soup using the below code :

```
soup = soup.find('div',id="capatcha")
```

I want to extract the content inside the label class that is - which one greater text.
Note that the id="j_idt40" is changing always.
I tried to split it by converting it to string but that did not help :(

```
<div class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget inline-section bottom-space-2" id="capatcha"><label class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget label-captcha" id="j_idt40">Which one is greater      3   ,   8</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.text` property to get text of the `<div>` tag. To get the particular numbers, you can use `re` module.

For example:

```
txt = '''<div class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget inline-section bottom-space-2" id="capatcha"><label class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget label-captcha" id="j_idt40">Which one is greater      3   ,   8</label></div>'''

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

text = soup.select_one('#capatcha').text
numbers = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', text)))

print(text)
print(numbers)
```

Prints:

```
Which one is greater      3   ,   8
[3, 8]
```